# Missing Table.Title property

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to find a table in a Word document by referencing `Table[1].Title` works when in a C# console project on my local computer.

However, the `Title` property is not available on the SharePoint server in a SharePoint solution even though the same references are within the Visual Studio solution.

Comment: Office installed on the server? I believe it's required if you're using the interop.

Comment: Yes. Office 2010 is installed on server. The code is working using the reference number - the number within the [ ]. The Title property would give us more control.

Comment: I found the answer to this problem. There were references in the project to both Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 12 and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 14. I removed all Interop references and then added a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 14. The Title property showed up.